# How to show data in function as a loop?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am beginner in flutter and following some tutorials. I need to know how can I show data in a function by looping? For now, I am calling function 2 or 3 times to show data on how its possible ill call function just one time and shop my data which is in array?

Here. my data file which name is post_model.dart

```
class Post {
  String authorName;
  String authorImageUrl;
  String timeAgo;
  String imageUrl;

  Post({
    this.authorName,
    this.authorImageUrl,
    this.timeAgo,
    this.imageUrl,
  });
}

final List<Post> posts = [
  Post(
    authorName: 'Umaiz Khan',
    authorImageUrl: 'assets/images/user0.png',
    timeAgo: '5 min',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/post0.jpg',
  ),
  Post(
    authorName: 'Saad ahmed',
    authorImageUrl: 'assets/images/user1.png',
    timeAgo: '10 min',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/post1.jpg',
  ),
  Post(
    authorName: 'Hiba',
    authorImageUrl: 'assets/images/user4.png',
    timeAgo: '10 min',
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/post2.jpg',
  ),
];

final List<String> stories = [
  'assets/images/user1.png',
  'assets/images/user2.png',
  'assets/images/user3.png',
  'assets/images/user4.png',
  'assets/images/user0.png',
  'assets/images/user1.png',
  'assets/images/user2.png',
  'assets/images/user3.png',
];
```

Here is my code at the end of the line you can see I am calling function and sending index. I need to call the function just one time and it will show all my arrays in data. Thanks in advance

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:mytravel/screens/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:mytravel/screens/guidePlacePage.dart';
import 'package:mytravel/models/post_model.dart';
import 'package:mytravel/screens/view_post_screen.dart';


class newsFeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _newsFeedPageState createState() => _newsFeedPageState();
}

class _newsFeedPageState extends State<newsFeedPage> {

  List<Widget> _buildPost() {
    List<Widget> items = [];

     items.add(
       Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 560.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Container(
                        width: 50.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black45,
                              offset: Offset(0, 2),
                              blurRadius: 6.0,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: Image(
                              height: 50.0,
                              width: 50.0,
                              image: AssetImage(posts[].authorImageUrl),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        posts[].authorName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(posts[].timeAgo),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                        color: Colors.black,
                        onPressed: () => print('More'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onDoubleTap: () => print('Like post'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => ViewPostScreen(
                              post: posts[],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 400.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black45,
                              offset: Offset(0, 5),
                              blurRadius: 8.0,
                            ),
                          ],
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(posts[].imageUrl),
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                    iconSize: 30.0,
                                    onPressed: () => print('Like post'),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '2,515',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
                                    iconSize: 30.0,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => ViewPostScreen(
                                            post: posts[],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '350',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            onPressed: () => print('Save post'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
      items.add(_buildPost(i));
    }

    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEDF0F6),
      body: ListView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Social Travel',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Billabong',
                    fontSize: 32.0,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),

          ListView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: _buildPost(),
          ),

        ],
      ),

    );
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the children array of your ListView in a new method like this :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEDF0F6),
    body: ListView(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: _buildListViewItems(),
    ),
  );
}

List<Widget> _buildListViewItems() {
  List<Widget> items = [];
  items.add(
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Instagram',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Billabong',
              fontSize: 32.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    items.add(_buildPost(i));
  }

  return items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but its showing error in items.add(_buildPost(i));  "the element type 'List<widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'"

Comment: You just had to apply my code and don't change anything else. The _buildPost() must return a Widget, not a list of widgets. Try and tell me if you don't succeed